# uframe load cross domain page

Tags: javascript, html, uframe

anyone know any workaround of using uframe  to load external uri ?  currently when i tried i get access denied on firefox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a server-side proxy page to grab external URLs and pull that in using ajax/XHR, then populate that.

```
$.get(
'proxy.php',
    {
        url:'http://www.sitename.com/'
    },
    function(data) {
        $('el').html( data );
    }

);
```

( assuming the .get invocation I have is in the correct form and you have jQuery loaded ).

And all proxy.php would do is check for $_GET['url'] and just echo the result of file_get_contents ( $_GET['url'] );